# Selectfield stuck in Sencha Touch & events not firing on selection

Tags: javascript, iphone, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a `selectfield` that works perfectly on desktop (*scrolls, selects, fires the right events, updates the appropriate field, etc.*), but will not disappear after selection when running on mobile (iPhone).

Upon making a selection, the selectfield "wheel" does not disappear and will not even disappear when tapping in the mask (outside of the scrolling picker area). Again, this only happens on mobile and is perfectly fine on desktop.

Sounds like a framework bug? Read on for more clues...

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    id: 'editor-page',
    name: 'page',
    label: 'Page',
    labelWidth: 70,
    options: [
        {text: 'N/A',  value: 'N/A'},
        {text: '1',  value: '1'},
        {text: '2',  value: '2'},
        {text: '3',  value: '3'}
        // ...
    ]
}
```

---

### Things I've tried (without luck)

- From what I've seen of similar issues around the web, I've tried messing with setting `showAnimation: 'false'`.
- Forcing `hideOnMaskTap: 'true'` (even though it should be by default)
- Setting `modal: 'true'`
- Setting `stopMaskTapEvent: 'false'` (to allow taps outside the picker to be made)

  **(AND... every combination of the above, just in case of framework quirk or a misunderstanding of their interdependence on my part.)**

---

### Selectfield events firing on desktop but not on mobile (iPhone)?

On the `selectfield`, I put listeners on the following events as a means to trap a selection change and force a `hide` or `blur`, but as it turns out, they're only firing on desktop (Chrome) and not in mobile Safari.

```
listeners: {
    'render': function (thisComponent) {
        alert("select!");                           
        thisComponent.blur();
    },
    'action': function (thisComponent) {
        alert("action!");
        thisComponent.blur();
    },
    'select': function (thisComponent) {
        alert("select!");
        thisComponent.blur();
    }
}
```

---

### And lastly, I hate to admit it, but yes, I'm using Sencha Touch 1.1.0

#### *Gasps! Oh the Horror!*

At this point, the project may not have time enough to consider all the ramifications of migrating to 2.x. Thus, this is my last ditch effort before diving into the migration if I absolutely must to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egad. So it turns out that although not rendered in the ***desktop*** browser, the ***mobile*** rendering of `selectfield` displays a set of "done" and "cancel" buttons.

Since the desktop version works upon selection without displaying these confirmation buttons, I had forgotten the mobile render of `selectfield` displays the confirmation buttons instead of being able to tap/click outside the picker or clear the mask upon making a selection.

In my particular case, I had some CSS toolbar rules that were obscuring the buttons within the `selectfield` picker.

Thus, it was only a matter of finding the right CSS selectors to reveal the buttons that (although not necessary or visible on desktop) were being hidden on mobile.

```
/* Override toolbar padding for selectfield confirmation toolbar */
.x-picker .x-toolbar .x-layout-box-inner {
    margin-top: -35px;
}
```